# How to apply power function in python

Tags: python

How can I calculate the values in the following pd df column ['Discount_rate']?

```
 y=0.35

     Age  Discount_rate
0    1    (1+y)^(-1)
1    2    (1+y)^(-2)
2    3    (1+y)^(-3)
3    4    (1+y)^(-4)
4    5    (1+y)^(-5)
5    6    (1+y)^(-6)
```

I wrote:
   df['Discount_rate']=(1+y)**(-df['Age'])

I got valueError message: 
  "Wrong number of items passed 32, placement implies 1"

Comment: @Daniel Mesejo: Thank you for your help. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [np.power](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

y = 0.35
data = [1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['ages'])
df['discount-rate'] = np.power(1 + y, -1 * df.ages.values)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   ages  discount-rate
0     1       0.740741
1     2       0.548697
2     3       0.406442
3     4       0.301068
4     5       0.223014
5     6       0.165195
```